# Why the intensity of a wave is $ \Psi \Psi^*$?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, complex-numbers, poynting-vector, intensity

In [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_from_slits#Mathematical_description) at the bottom, it says the intensity of a wave is the wave phasor times it's conjucate

$$ I(x) = \Psi \Psi^* = |\Psi |^2$$

But when I compute the intensity of an electromagnetic wave in c.g.s, I get,

$$ I = \langle S \rangle = \langle \vec{E} \times \vec{B} \rangle = \frac{1}{2} A^2$$

Where,

$$ \vec{E} = \vec{E_0} e^{i(\omega t - \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})}  $$
$$ \vec{B} = \vec{B_0} e^{i(\omega t - \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})}  $$
$$ | \vec{E_0}| = |\vec{B_0}| = A $$

Is $A^2$ not equal to $|\Psi|^2$?

Is it because they use a radial wave?

If so, then can someone please show me what are the differences when computing the time average poynting vector?

[image]

Comment: Here's a hint. What is $sin^2 \theta + cos^2 \theta$? So with that, what is the average of $\sin^2 \theta$?

Comment: @Dan The average is $1/2$  that's how I got to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article you linked to from Wikipedia, $|\Psi|$ and $|A|$ differ by a factor of r.

$$
|\Psi|^2 = \frac{|A|^2}{r^2}
$$

They can't generally be equal. They can't even have the same units.

For the spherical wave described in the linked article, the intensity is going to fall of like 1/r^2. You performed calculations for a plane wave, which is not the same thing.